# Possible leak from upstairs window into downstairs window

Tags: windows, leak

I have a leak in the wall facing outside.  There is damage in the cieling directly above the window.  Note that this issue only happens about once every 6 months to 1 year.  I think when the wind is just right during rain storms.

[image]

Snake camera inside of hole

[image]

I'm guessing the water comes from the second story window directly above.  Is this metal something that can be caulked?  Or should I replace it?

The window itself was recently replaced as part of this issue.  However, the issue is still there.  I'm thinking the metal housing the window is also a problem.

[image]

Comment: In the top picture, not only is the hole a problem, but also it looks like the caulking has pulled away from the frame. Water can get in either way. In many cases you could caulk up both issues, but in this case there may be too much underlying water damage to just seal it up and forget about it. It looks like there's some moisture damage above the place where the hole is also.

Comment: You may have additional leaks further up. Not sure what the middle picture is, but the bottom picture supports the conclusion that there is extensive internal damage that needs to be taken care of before eventually sealing everything back up. Any chance of posting more pictures of the wall above the windows and maybe a little further back to provide some context?

Comment: Are these pictures showing the exterior or interior of the building? I'm mostly asking about the top photo.

Comment: All of these are interior.

Comment: The pictures you posted all show signs of extensive water damage inside the walls and to the drywall/plaster. This is quite a bit bigger than something you can fix with a tube of calk. You're probably going to have to deal with rotted wood, replacing drywall, insulation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I setup a claim with insurance

Comment: Insurance came out and gave me a quote for fixing the obvious damage.  No idea about mold. Super unhelpful guy.  Seemed to have no idea what to do here.  And he had no clue on the blue coloring inside the wall in the pics above.  Basically said since this isn't a "1 time issue" rather a damage over time issue then my coverage is almost non-existant.  And he will not help diagnose anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several years of fighting this issue and asking many experts, I finally have a solution.  I attached a garden nozzle with a high pressure setting.  Then I sprayed the windows all over the corners and edges.  Nothing.

So I started looking at the bricks.  I found several places that looked like holes.  I sprayed those.  FINALLY.  Water came into the house.  The mortar came loose from the brick and caused the leak.  I'm going to plug it up with [Quikrete Mortar Repair Sealant.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-10-oz-Mortar-Repair-Sealant-862009/100318502#customer_reviews)

If I had a buddy I would have also tried a leaf blower.  I figure if water can get through then so can air.  I was going to push the leaf blower into the hole in my window then go look for a place where air is blowing out.

I credit Dan Schweihs at [The Window Dog](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfgSE3_b-LHnHjvpzxqvP0g) for helping to finally reproduce the problem.  And I'm thankful he did NOT blindly sell me windows that would not have fixed my primary concern (as several other window companies did).